# How to make Hyperlink TableColumn in TableView editable

Tags: javafx, hyperlink, tableview, tablecolumn

```
 TableColumn<ComponentObject, Hyperlink> template_id = new TableColumn<ComponentObject, Hyperlink>("Template Id");
    template_id.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<ComponentObject, Hyperlink>("template"));

   template_id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    template_id.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<ComponentObject, Hyperlink>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<ComponentObject, Hyperlink> t) {
                ((ComponentObject) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setTemplate((javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink) t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    );
```

Here setCellFactory is giving error as 
"

```
The method setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<ComponentObject,Hyperlink>,TableCell<ComponentObject,Hyperlink>>) in 
 the type TableColumn<ComponentObject,Hyperlink> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Callback<TableColumn<Object,String>,TableCell<Object,String>>)
```

"

How to solve this? I want to make template_id column editable..but note that it is hyperlink..

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to specify a `stringConverter` for the `TextFieldTableCell`:

```
StringConverter<Hyperlink> converter = new StringConverter<Hyperlink>() {

    @Override
    public Hyperlink fromString(String string) {
        return new Hyperlink(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Hyperlink hyperlink) {
        return hyperlink.getText();
    }
}

template_id.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(converter));
```

In general, though, it is a very bad idea to represent your data with UI nodes, which is what you are doing by making the column type a `Hyperlink`. Strange things may happen here. It would be better to make the data type `String`, and to implement your own `TableCell` that showed a `Hyperlink` when not in editing mode, and a `TextField` when in editing mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Can you give an example of how to implement a tablecell that will show hyperlink when not in editing mode and a textfield in editing mode?